# Prove that the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ exists if and only if $a$ and $m$ are coprime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ exists if and only if $a$ and $m$ are coprime.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: $I'd like you to show some effort. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: $a,m$ coprime implies the existence of integers $r,s$ s.t. $ra+sm=1$ (lemma of Bezout).

Hint2:

If $ra=1$ mod $m$ then $m|ra-1$ so that $ra-1=sm$ for some integer $m$

Comment: i can prove this one. My problem is the other way round, which is if multiplicative inverse exists, then a,m are cop rime

Comment: The existence of multiplicative inverse implies the existence of integer $r,s$ with $ra+sm=1$. If $d=gcd(a,m)$ then $d$ divides $ra+sm=1$ so $d$ must be $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose there exists a multiplicative inverse q such that

$aq \equiv 1\ (mod\ m) \implies aq - 1 = mk \implies aq + mk_1 = 1 \implies gcd(a,m) = 1$ can be easily proven I will leave it as excerise to you how I reached that last step.

Now going the other side

Suppose that $gcd(a,m) = 1 \implies ay_1 + mq_1 = 1 \implies ay_1 \equiv 1 \ (mod\ m)$, so multiplicative inverse exists.

I have taken few short-cuts since some steps are trivial to complete but if you don't see it right away I can modify my answer.

Comment: would you mind explicitly stating how you got to the gcd(a, m)=1 step in your first proof?

Comment: You can do it directly. Constructing gcd is as follows you can easily prove that $gcd(a,b) = min\{ au + mv : au + mv > 0\}$ Here we are considering the integers by well ordering principle such number exist. As integers begin with 1, so that is minimum such possible.

Comment: You can do a more elementary argument, but this is as deep as you can get.